# Ubuntu 22.04 auto scrolled to the top

Tags: gnome, 22.04, mouse, touchpad

For last couple of days I'm facing this issue. After some times system automatically scrolled to the top of the window (Browser|Windows|Terminal|...). All my settings seems normal. Anyone facing this issue? or anyone knows how to fix this? Thank you.

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad`

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag-lock false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-button-map 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true
```

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse`

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse double-click 400
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse drag-threshold 8
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 0.0
```

Comment: If it's happening in multiple applications sporadically, it's likely hardware. Keyboards are mechanical and can exhibit this behaviour. Food stuck under the `Home` keyboard key, would be my bet.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. I unplugged all external devices but still that happening.

Comment: What is your windowing system?
If it's `x11`, see if changing it to `wayland` ([how to change](https://beebom.com/how-switch-between-wayland-xorg-ubuntu/)) fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the screen reader, which can be found in accessibility settings. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer needs some supporting info.